# How to determine the convergence of this series where no formal rule exists in sigma notation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The series is as follows:

$1 + \frac 12 - \frac 13 + \frac 14 + \frac 15 - \frac 16 + \frac 17 + \frac 18 - \frac 19...$

I've tried grouping terms together with no avail at seeing a pattern.

Comment: If the pattern is two positive numbers followed by a negative, then that can be expressed as $-(-1)^{\sin n\pi/3}$.  That won't help you find the convergence, but at least will let you use sigma notation.

Comment: $1+\dfrac12-\dfrac23+\dfrac14+\dfrac15-\dfrac26+\dfrac17+\dfrac18-\dfrac29 + \cdots~=~\ln3$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: grouping each negative term with the immediately preceding positive one, tells us that the partial sums are at least as big as the partial sums of $$1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{10}+\cdots =\sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{1}{3n+1}$$

Comment: Brilliant, I can't believe that didn't hit me. Thanks!

Comment: But this is not a series of positive terms so grouping is not available. The series is understood to be a sequence of partial sums, nothing more.

Comment: *if* the original series converges, then the sequence of partial sums will converge.  But the above selections from the partial sums (every third partial sum) diverges by the above.  That's why this is a hint.

Comment: You are right. I did not read your answer carefully enough!